# How Do You Get All Solar In A Single Starting Drop?

Tags: awesomenauts

I purchased Awesomenauts a few days ago because of my friends recommendation and have talked about it with him quite a bit.  He then told me that there is an achievement for getting all solar in a single starting drop.  This seems pretty impossible and I haven't found anything on it but if this can happen how do you do it?

Comment: The first thing I do when it comes to trophies (or achievements), is to check any [guide or roadmap](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/awesomenauts/156784-awesomenauts-trophy-guide-roadmap.html) for the game.

Answer (score 6):

The achievement/trophy your friend probably referred to is **Wings of Silver** which requires you get 35 solar on a single drop, not all of the solar.

Some guides online suggest memorizing the pattern and doing this in practice mode. Here's a video I've found at [TrueAchievements](http://www.trueachievements.com/a164062/wings-of-silver-achievement.htm) that shows how this can be achieved: